# Get contact display picture with a phone number without a country code?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get a contact's display picture regardless of whether the number exactly matches to that in the address book?

For exmample - if the number saved is 736--------, but the incoming call shows +01736--------, how do I get the display picture using the number with the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the display image of the contact based on the contact number(whichever format it is).

Below method will return the display image of a contact if the contact is stored in the device contacts list and that contact has the image. Pass the contact number with or without country code.

```
public static Bitmap getDisplayPhoto(Context context, String contactNumber) {

        contactNumber = Uri.encode(contactNumber);
        int phoneContactID = -1;
        Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, contactNumber),
                new String[] { PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID }, null, null, null);
        while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()) {
            phoneContactID = contactLookupCursor.getInt(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
        }
        contactLookupCursor.close();

        Bitmap photo = null;
        if (phoneContactID != -1) {
            Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, phoneContactID);
            Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");

                photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd.getFileDescriptor());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        return photo;
    }
```

Comment: That's not enough for an answer. I'm not asking you to write the app, but even theoretical info would do. You could just post this as a comment.

Comment: Do you want code to get the display image from contact number??

Comment: Read the question. I want it to retrieve the display picture regardless of the country code.

Comment: How do I make this code return null if a contact has no picture? Currently it returns just a plain white pic.

Comment: This method will return null only if there is no pic for contact. Once check it properly(change the background color of the activity and see or check for the null using if condition).